# How to use stateful services (databases) in Rancher?

Tags: docker, rancher

I need to use Postgres database in Rancher stack (Cattle).
I made environment for my application, that contains api, frontend and database services (in one stack). I want to use multiple hosts for this environment, but if I will add some hosts, database can't properly work, because volume with data will only exists on one host.

I think, I cannot use NFS (or some other network storage) for databases because of IO speed. Am I right? Is there any workflow to use databases in Rancher?

I thought, that I can bind service only to one host of environment, but I didn't find this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Rancher has [Storage Services](http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/latest/en/rancher-services/storage-service/) to manage [Volumes](http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/latest/en/cattle/volumes/).

NFS (`rancher-nfs`) will not work very well for a read/write Postgres database. If you're running on AWS Rancher also supports EBS volumes via [convoy](https://github.com/rancher/convoy)

For vanilla Docker `local` is the only volume type that will work in most places but these are obviously not shared volumes, it's local to the Docker host. If you create an environment scoped `local` volume for the database then the database container will always be scheduled to the node holding the storage.

Other shared storage volume types require the storage backend and a Docker volume plugin that can manage the movements of external storage. [REX-Ray](https://github.com/rexray/rexray) supports a number of [storage providers](https://github.com/rexray/rexray#storage-provider-support). [Flocker](https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker) also supports a number of [storage providers](https://flocker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported/index.html#supported-infrastructure-storage).